# Select records from a table, which don't exist in another table whilst keep records from one table where there are multiple

Tags: sql, hadoop

I have 2 tables TABLE1 and TABLE2 in hadoop imparla. TABLE 2 has some of the records of the TABLE1. What I want is to select all the records from TABLE 1, which don't exist in TABLE2 and then combine so I end up with a table containing all the records from TABLE2 and records from TABLE1 that are not in TABLE2 So I coded:

```
String sq = "SELECT TABLE1.name, TABLE1.surname, TABLE1.id FROM TABLE1"
            + "LEFT JOIN TABLE1"
            + "ON TABLE1.id <> TABLE2.id";
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You should check with where matching value  is null in table2

```
String sq = "SELECT TABLE1.name, TABLE1.surname, TABLE1.id FROM TABLE1"
        + "LEFT JOIN TABLE2"
        + "ON TABLE1.id = TABLE2.id"
        + "WHETE TABLE2.id IS NULL ";
```